# Mark for 'come back later' while reviewing document

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, office365, review

While reviewing documents in ms-word (version 365), and in review-mode, I would like to mark a text/paragraph as 'to come back to later'.

The purpose of this would be to check for text consistency.

Functionwise it should fullfill the following requirements

- it should stand out visually (especially from other comments in the document you made while reviewing)
- optimal and somewhat optional: give me a summary at the end of the document (you're done reading
  everything, now check for consistency errors and things you marked
  previously)
- it should be easy to iterate through it, similar to the grammar/orthography correction provided by ms-word

I can't imagine an easy solution for this problem based on my current ms-word knowledge. How is this currently achieved by the community (/more experienced users)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things come to mind. The first is to insert comments. I believe those meet most of your criteria. Here is the [Microsoft Support page on comments](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-comments-in-a-document-95a93b1e-aaea-4c8d-a25d-8f91eb217390).

Otherwise, I would consider using a Frame in the margin. This can be made a part of a style and you can type in it. Since it can be a style, you can apply it using a keyboard shortcut. Styles can be located using Find and iterated through as well. Here is my [page on frames](http://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm#sidebars).

[Edit: adding screenshots]

**Marginal Frame Using Paragraph Style**

[image: Marginal Frame using Style]

**Comment marked with Character Style**

[image: Comment marked with style]

**Search for note by the style applied**

[image: Search for note by the style applied]

Comment: I guess it should stand out clearly among other comments, was the idea. Is there a way to mark/highlight/bookmark review comments?

Comment: You could use a character style in the comment to make it stand out - with shading and text color. Again you can apply such a style using a keyboard shortcut with Ctrl+Spacebar to return to the underlying Comment paragraph style. Otherwise, look into the suggestion to use a style that has a Frame as part of the formatting to create these custom notes..

Comment: I've added some screenshots.

Comment: ok, this is the best workaround I've come across so far, thank you